# Bar with 3 Measures in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

How can I create a bar chart, similar to the one in the image in Tableau desktop.
I've tried creating a stacked bar and a Gantt chart, but they don't give me what I need.

The Fundraising Goal will be the entire bar, with the gifts received covering its respective amount of the bar and the "to be raised" covering the remaining (the difference between both).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say your column names are `[category]` and `[value]` respectively.

1. Drag `SUM([value])` to rows, drag `[category]` to color in the
   marks pane, and choose *Bar Chart* in the dropdown above it.
2. Drag `[category]` to your filters pane and only include *'Gifts
   Received to Date'* and *'To be Raised'*; conversely just exclude
   *'Fundraising Goal'*.
3. Format the label in the marks pane to match your above example.

Check out the documentation for Stacked Bar Chart [here](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/stacked-bar-chart-multiple-measures).

Comment: Another variation is to plot Gifts Received to Date as a bar chart, and then add Fundraising Goal as a reference line (see the Analytics Tab in the top left)